# Automatic partitioning in PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, database-partitioning

I have a table with many millions of rows, so I think a list partitioned table might be a good idea.

I have done a hunt around and cannot determine if these partitions can be created automatically.

If I try to insert a row into the partitioned table, I would like a new partition created where necessary when the row’s partition key does not pertain to an existing partition.

Is this a thing yet? If not, how might I accomplish this?

Comment: See [pg_partman](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman) and [pg_partman howto](https://github.com/pgpartman/pg_partman/blob/master/doc/pg_partman_howto_native.md).

Comment: I don't think there is a way to have [partitions created automatically](https://www.cybertec-postgresql.com/en/automatic-partition-creation-in-postgresql/).